# Gears keep auto dropping esp in hills

Tags: crankset

My bike is 10 years old and has Shimano ultegra triple crankset.

Being my first road bike, I assumed it was my skill when the gears would drop on their own or kick the chain off. I took it in to shop several times and the mechanic would tinker with the derailleur or other parts. I have changed the chain a few time but the problem never stops.  Suggestions?  I am at the point of just getting all new crankset.

Comment: Usually when the shifting is not accurate or the chain falls of the chainrings then it's a straight forward job to adjust the cable tension and limiter screws. But if a mechanic has tried to adjust this already then it must be less straightforward. How old is the crank set and chainrings?

Comment: Does this happen at the front, ie the chain rings at the crank set, only. Or also at the rear, the cassette? Please describe a little which gears you run when it happens.

Comment: Has this always happened, and how many miles do you estimate you have on the bike?  One does wonder whether the mechanic is competent.  You might try a different shop if you can.  But having this happen so regularly on a hill hints at a possible problem with the frame flexing, either affecting the chainline or simply causing the shift cables to change tension.  (Has this always happened, and how many miles do you estimate you have on the bike?)

Answer (score 1):

> changed the chain a few times

Have you also changed any of the corresponding drive-train ie. cassette and / or chainrings?

Check the wear on your cassette. If the teeth are thinned-out the cassette is also worn and you will need to replace this also.
Check the chain-rings - if these resemble shark-fins these are also worn out.

Unfortunately drive train wears together and replacing one part of them often creates a skipping gear where the chain no longer sits comfortably on the drive train due to *previous* wear.